# Overwrite an already generated form using doctrine:generate:form?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

When running this:

`php app/console doctrine:generate:form  ProjectFrontendBundle:Car`

Im getting this message below if the form type class already exists.

> Unable to generate the CarType form class as it already exists under
>   the ~/workspace/certifi/src/Project/FrontendBundle/Form/CarType.php
>   file

So, is possible to overwrite an already generated form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at `app/console doctrine:generate:form -h` suggests no unfortunately:

```
Options:
  -h, --help               Display this help message
  -q, --quiet              Do not output any message
  -V, --version            Display this application version
      --ansi               Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi            Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction     Do not ask any interactive question
  -s, --shell              Launch the shell.
      --process-isolation  Launch commands from shell as a separate process.
  -e, --env=ENV            The Environment name. [default: "dev"]
      --no-debug           Switches off debug mode.
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose     Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

I guess you just delete the existing type class (or `mv` it if you are feeling cautious and not using a vcs).

Comment: It would be a nice feature though since `doctrine:generate:entities` automatically backs up and regenerates existing entities.

Comment: Sounds like a nice improvement to the command, think it is best if you open an issue on Github about a "force overwrite" parameter.

Comment: Perhaps! I'll see if I can find the time :)